# Distribution based on probability

Tags: excel, statistics, average, probability, mean

What is the best way to distribute a value based on historical percentages.
I am trying to distribute the value 5000 based on previous averages for the month

I have tried with averages but doesn't work as the sum does not add up to 100% i.e 5000

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct average for `Product 4` and `Product 5` you should add `0%` in empty cells. Then you will get right amount.

[image]